# the definition of a.s. convergence

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, limsup-and-liminf, almost-everywhere

One of the definitions of a.s. convergence is
$X_n \overset{a.s.}{\to} a$ if for any $\varepsilon > 0$

$$
P( \liminf_{n\to\infty} A_n) =1
$$
where $A_n = \{ \omega \in \Omega: |X_{n}(\omega) - a| < \varepsilon\}$.

Therefore, $X_n \overset{a.s.}{\to} a$ means that for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists finite $n_0$, which depends ONLY on $a$ and $\varepsilon$ such that for all $n > n_{0}$ one has

$$
P(A_n) =1
$$

Is this correct? If not, what is the correct description in words of this definition?

Comment: Do you mean $P(\liminf A_n) = 0$? Otherwise we would have almost surely no convergence to $a$.

Comment: it was a typo, of course, $|X_n - a| < \varepsilon$.

Comment: on which $\omega$?

Comment: In that case $n_0$ is still a random variable, i.e. it depends on each $\omega$ itself from what point onwards $\omega \in A_n$ for all $n\ge n_0(\omega)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This result is not true. The statement
$$
P\left(\liminf_{n\to\infty}A_n\right)=1
$$
means that there exists a set $\Omega'\subseteq \Omega$ such that $P(\Omega') = 1$ and for each $\omega\in\Omega'$ there exists an $n_0(\omega)$ such that $\omega\in A_n$ for all $n\ge n_0(\omega)$.

Comment: Is it possible to have a non-trivial case when there is a universal non-random $n_0$ which does not depend on $\omega$

Comment: To avoid the dependence of $n_0$ on $\omega$ you would have to require that the domain of $X_n$ is bounded around $a$ and converges to that point. Take for example $U_1,U_2,\ldots\thicksim$ Uniform$(-1,1)$ and $X_n = a + \frac{U_n}{n}$.

Answer (score 1):

Not true. Let $E_n$ be any disjoint collection of events each having positive probability. Then $I_{E_n} \to 0$ a.s. but $P(A_n)<1$ for all $n$.